# LoadLibrary API Fails with 998 (ERROR_NOACCESS)

Tags: windows-7-x64, loadlibrary, vcproj

The API `LoadLibrary()` fails with my MFC application when run over a Windows 7 64-bit PC. It returns error 998 for a specific DLL. This DLL is built over a 32-bit machine. But no issues to load other DLLs.

I have tried excluding this MFC application from DEP, but still same issue.

But what surprised me is that, when I wrote a sample console application to check this by using the same API to load the problematic DLL, it worked as expected.

Can someone tell me the reason for this issue?